# UCanAccess not working after JAR creation

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am using ucanaccess 2.0.9.1 and jackcess 2.0.5 for my Java program and the connection to my MS Access database. In eclipse luna, the connection is working perfectly but after creating the JAR, the connection is not working anymore.

Does anyone have a hint why the connection is not working anymore?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WORKING NOW: I used for JAR creation: "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" but now I used: "Package required libraries into generated JAR" which is working! :-)

Answer (score 0):

From asker's comment to the question:

> WORKING NOW: I used for JAR creation: "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" but now I used: "Package required libraries into generated JAR" which is working! :-)